# cannot seem to sort an Array of objects by date

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

```
class newPlanner{

    private  newAppointment[] Appoint = new newAppointment[20];

    newPlanner(){
        newAppointment obj1 = new newAppointment("Mar",4,17,30,"Quiz 1");

        newAppointment obj2 = new newAppointment("Apr",1,17,30,"Midterm");

        newAppointment obj3 = new newAppointment("May",6,17,30,"Quiz 2");

        newAppointment obj4 = new newAppointment("Jun",3,17,30,"Final");

        Appoint [0] = obj4;
        Appoint [1] = obj3;
        Appoint [2] = obj2;
        Appoint [3] = obj1;

    }

    public void runMethod(){
        boolean answer = true;

        while (answer) {
            System.out.println("Select an Option. ");
            System.out.println(" 1. Add Appointment ");  
            System.out.println(" 2. List Appointment ");
            System.out.println(" 3. Delete Appointment ");
            System.out.println(" 4. Exit ");
```

this is my code and i need to create a method that shifts the array elements to insert a new appointment, and delete appointments. The array needs to be  sorted by date and I just cant seem to get it Please Help

Comment: What language is this ? Java ?

Don't use arrays, use a List, and then do Collections.sort on it.

Comment: yes java and i would but we have to explicitly use an array

Comment: If you really need an array at the end use `List.toArray` to convert it back.

This looks like some sort of academic coding problem, In the real world no one would use arrays for this sort of thing, that's what the collections API was invented for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort an array in-place using [`Arrays.sort(T[] a,Comparator<? super T> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)), where `T` is your `Appointment` class.

You will need to implement the `Comparator` interface for `Appointment`. This would be a lot easier if your `Appointment` class took a [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object in the constructor; then your comparator would simply be:

```
Arrays.sort(appointments, new Comparator<Appointment>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Appointment appointment1, Appointment appointment2){
        return appointment1.getDate().compareTo(appointment2.getDate());
    }
});
```

You can determine the date of your `Appointment` class as follows:

```
public class Appointment{
    /**
    * three letter month
    */
    private final String month;

    /**
    * one to two digit day e.g. 1 or 12,
    */
    private final int day;

    /**
    * two digit military time hour e.g. 01, 11, 17
    */
    private final int hour;

    /**
    * lazily instantiated appointment Date
    */
    private Date date;

    //..

    public class Appointment(String month, int day, int hour /*other parameters*/){
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        this.hour = hour;

        calculateDate();
    }

    private void caculateDate(){
        String dateString = String.format("%d %s 2018 %d",day,month,hour);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy HH");

        try{
            this.date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Date getDate(){
        return date;
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the appointment classes takes a constructor however in the form month, day,hour,description

Comment: You'll need to convert that into a date. To do this you could create a date String and then parse it using `SimpleDateFormat`. e.g. you could create a string `4 Mar 2018 17` and parse it using the format `d MMM yyyy HH`

Comment: sorry i didnt correctly explain its string month, int day, int hour int min string description

Comment: Yes, I understood that. You can convert these values into a date. First,   create a date string string e.g. `String.format("%d %s 2018 %d",day,month,hour);`. Then convert this string into a date using `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: String a = Integer.toString(day);
       String b = Integer.toString(hour);
       String c = Integer.toString(min);
       String abc = month +a+b+c;
       Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM","dd","hh","mm").parse(abc);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
 cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList for `AppPoint`. Write your own custom-comparator. Use `Collections.sort(appPoint, new <CustomComparator>())`

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean compareAppointment (newAppointment A1, newAppointment A2) {

    String [] validMonth = {"JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL",
                            "AUG", "SEP", "OCT","NOV","DEC"};

    int a=0;
    int b=0;

    for ( int i = 0; i< validMonth.length; i++) {
      if (A1.getMonth() == null ? validMonth[i] == null : A1.getMonth().equals(validMonth[i])) {
        a=i;
      }

      if (A2.getMonth() == null ? validMonth[i] == null : A2.getMonth().equals(validMonth[i])) {
        b = i;
      }
    }

    if (a!=b) {
      return a < b;
    }

    if (A1.getDay() != A2.getDay()) {
      return A1.getDay() < A2.getDay();
    }

    if (A1.getHourr()!= A2.getHourr()) {
      return A1.getHourr() < A2.getHourr();
    }

    if (A1.getMinn() != A2.getMinn()) {
      return A1.getMinn() < A2.getMinn();
    }

    return false;
}
```